# My CSS is not displaying my background image

Tags: html, css, image, background-image

I created an external css file but the background image is not displaying. I validated the file and it says there is no error and other elements are still applied, so I am not sure what i did wrong. Any solution?
Here is the code:

```
body {
  background-image: url(../images/wordwall.jpg);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried inspecting and checking the background image path?

Comment: @DebsmitaPaul I am new at this how do I check?

Comment: In Chrome, you can press Ctrl+Shift+i or simply F12 to open developer tool. Then navigate to body tag of your html structure.

Answer (score 2):

Usually problems like this are caused by a wrong filepath. The file path here has to be relative to the CSS file, so your filepath would work if the stylesheet is an a folder which is at the same level as the `images` folder. If that's not the case, you need to change it, otherwise your CSS file might not be referenced correctly.

Comment: ok checked the file path and there was a spelling error thank you for the help

Answer (score 1):

This most likely has to do with the file path, try checking again and make sure all spellings are correct.

PS: '.. /' takes you one step backward from the file you're working on.